Wi-Fi Adapter Not Recognized on Ubuntu 22.04 - Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174
I'm having a frustrating issue with my Ubuntu 22.04 system where my Wi-Fi adapter is not being recognized, and I can't connect to any Wi-Fi networks. Here's a summary of the problem:
System Information:

OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Wi-Fi Adapter: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
Driver: ath10k_pci
Current Firmware: WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1

Problem Description:

The Wi-Fi adapter appears as DISABLED when I check using lshw -C network.
The device status shows unmanaged in nmcli device status.
When I try to scan for Wi-Fi networks using nmcli device wifi rescan, I get the error: "Error: Scanning not allowed while unavailable."
I've tried using rfkill to unblock Wi-Fi, but it doesn't solve the issue. rfkill list shows that Wi-Fi is not blocked.
The adapter was previously working when I was setting up a Wi-Fi hotspot using hostapd. After that, I couldn't connect to any Wi-Fi network.

Steps I've Tried:

Reinstalling NetworkManager: Ensured NetworkManager is installed and up to date.
Reloading the driver: Tried modprobe -r ath10k_pci and modprobe ath10k_pci to reload the Wi-Fi driver.

I'm out of ideas at this point. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or could suggest further troubleshooting steps? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Did it ever work?

Yes, it was working fine before. I was able to use the Wi-Fi adapter without any issues. The problem started after I set up a Wi-Fi hotspot using hostapd. Since then, I haven't been able to connect to any Wi-Fi networks.

Have you tried reversing the steps you took to setup Wi-Fi hotspot using hostapd? I guess, if the WiFi adapter is used as a hotspot you can't use the same WiFi to connect to the Internet.

Yes, I have already reversed the steps and uninstalled everything related to the Wi-Fi hotspot

Open a terminal and enter the commands sudo lspci and sudo lshw -C network | grep "driver" then directly copy and paste the output of these commands from your terminal to the question above. You can follow the instructions on this site for the next steps.
